# Start Developer PowerShell for VS 2019 from Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, virtual-machine, azure-pipelines

We have configured a windows virtual machine and deployed an agent there to build our code and run scripts.

In our VM we two different flavors of PowerShell command prompt:

1. Windows PowerShell
2. Developer PowerShell for VS 2019.

How can we start  "Developer PowerShell for VS 2019" from our pipeline YAML script and execute our checked out `.ps1` file there?

There are several flavors of PowerShell tasks that can be initiated from the pipeline though and not sure which one of them will serve the purpose. They are the following:

1. Azure PowerShell
2. PowerShell
3. PowerShell on Target Machine
4. Service Fabric PowerShell.

Which of the above represent "Developer PowerShell for VS 2019"?

The reason behind this specific flavor of PowerShell is:

1. Need to have some of the .NET Framework Tools (CorFlags.exe) which are only accessible in the "Developer PowerShell for VS 2019" and not in the other one.

Answer (score 3):

The **Developer PowerShell for VS 2019** is a regular PowerShell with a module imported, you can see exactly what in this way:

- Go the Start menu and search for **Developer PowerShell for VS 2019**.
- Right-click on it and **Open file location** - you will get this:

[image]

- Now right-click again on the **Developer PowerShell for VS 2019** shortcut and **Properties**.
- You will see in the **location** that is run the regular PowerShell with some command:

  `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell bc97b47b}"`

[image]

Now, if you open a PowerShell and run the script there:

```
&{Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"; Enter-VsDevShell bc97b47b}
```

You will get the Developer PowerShell for VS 2019 and CoreFlags.exe will work:

[image]

So, you need to use the regular PowerShell task (your option 2) and run the above command at the begging of the script.

*Note: you should copy exactly the command you see in the **Properties**, in each machine it could be different.*

Comment: If someone has to call for the "Developer PowerShell for VS 2019" on 100 machines, she/he has to copy the command 100 times, because for each machine it could be different. Do you think it is considered to be a good process for automation ?

Comment: But it one time for good, maybe you can write a script that extract the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft came up with a solution to this issue:

[Launch Developer PowerShell by script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell#developer-powershell)

You need to find that script in your `Program Files` folder (something similar to `Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\' -Recurse -Filter 'Launch-VsDevShell.ps1'`) and use that path.